# How can I add an application name at the start of a Razor Pages route?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, routes, razor-pages

Say I have a RazorPages application with pages in folders under the Pages folder like in the image below:

[image]

pretty standard. I want this application to be available for different clients so that they use different URLs to access it.  I can use a `@page "/RRate/Index/{sName}"` directive in the RRate\Index.cshtml file so that the URL `<root>\RRate\Index\client_name`will bind client_name to sName.

My question is: Can I use a URL like `<root>\client_name\RRate\Index` so that the client name is the first part of the route?  How would I implement a route like that?

Not surprisingly, a `@page "/{sName}/RRate/Index"` directive does not work.

I am using .NET Core 3.1, `services.AddRazorPages();` and `endpoints.MapRazorPages();` in startup.

I have looked at `endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute()` but this approach does not seem to mesh with Razor pages. Am I wrong?

Comment: Odd, it can work on my side, could you show us your startup.cs, also take a look at  this [article](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#route-data).

Comment: Thanks @mj1313! As often, the real help is a link to the precise article!

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer was in the [article](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#route-data) mentioned by @mj1313.

I added PageRoutes for each page (I wander if there is a way to do this in one route) like the following: `options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/RRate/Index", "{survey}/RRate/Index");`.